# After using git to locally track a project, how can I add it to GitHub?

Tags: git, github

After using git to locally track a project, how can I add it to GitHub?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

GitHub gives you instructions after you've created the repository online.

`cd` to the directory with the local repository

`git remote add origin whatever-address-my-repository is.git` to set the remote

then make a commit, and push to the master branch.

`git push -u origin master`

https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo

Comment: `git remote add origin whatever-address-my-repository is.git` and `git push origin HEAD:master`

Comment: Great, thanks! Also, how do I make git not ask me the username every time?

Comment: @Bane once you have added your repo to remote, just push it with `git push -u origin master` after the commit. you will only be asked your ssh key.

Comment: If you want to push ALL your local branches and tags to GitHub, and not just master, use `git push --all -u origin`.

Comment: There are two ways. If you're using GIT through SSL (https), then you can take advantage of the credential helper (http://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials). If, on the other hand you're using SSH, then you get to create a local key and then upload it to GitHub so it won't ask you because it checks the RSA key (https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage)

Comment: Why does this answer start with "no not really"?

Answer (score 4):

1.Create a `README.md` in your local repo (for GitHub -`*optional`)

2.`git remote add origin <your_URL_for_github_repo.git>`

(You can verify you have `origin` by entering `git remote -v`. You could see `<URL>.git` as the `origin`).

3.Make a commit by `git commit -a -m "<a message>"`

(Important! Only committed files will be pushed to Github)

4.Now push to GitHub by `git push -u origin master` (If you pushing the master branch).

You will be needing passwords every time you push (If you cloned using `https:`).For get rid of that ;

In Terminal, enter the following:

```
git config --global credential.helper cache
# Set git to use the credential memory cache
```

To change the default password cache timeout, enter the following:

```
git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=3600'
# Set the cache to timeout after 1 hour (setting is in seconds)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you will find the steps about how to create a repository and how to push it on Github: http://programertools.blogspot.com/2014/04/how-to-use-github.html